# CKEditor режет код

Tags: ckeditor

Вставляю код в источник

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=79000000000" target="_blank" title="Написать в Whatsapp" rel="noopener noreferrer"><div class="whatsapp-button"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></div></a>
```

Сохраняю, захожу в источник, CKEditor меняет код на это

```
<div class="whatsapp-button">&nbsp;</div>
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?